# Open pre-defined windows automatically when opening Byobu

Tags: byobu

I would like Byobu to start with 4 windows (Byobu in the Byobu sense, not in the Ubuntu sense):

- One window showing `top`
- One window showing a `bash` in `/`
- One window showing a `bash` in $HOME
- One window showing a `vim` on an existing file

So I wrote this in my `~/.byoburc`:

```
byobu new-session -s my -n Top -d "top"
byobu new-window -t my -d -n Root -c /
byobu new-window -t my -d -n Personal
byobu new-window -t my -d -n Notes -d "vim /home/nico/notes.txt"
```

And now byobu does not even start, I guess it just calls itself. So I tried removing the `byobu` part:

```
new-session -s my -n Top -d "top"
new-window -t my -d -n Root -c /
new-window -t my -d -n Personal
new-window -t my -d -n Notes -d "vim /home/nico/notes.txt"
```

But it says it does not find the `new-session` command.

**QUESTION:** What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If you read `man byobu` , specifically **WINDOWS** section, it says:

> Users  can create a list of windows to launch at startup in
>   `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows` and `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows.tmux`.  This
>   file is the
>          same syntax as `~/.screenrc` and `~/.tmuxrc`, each line specifying a window, as described in screen(1) or tmux(1).

So running byobu and doing `echo $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR` tells me the files are in `/home/username/.byobu`. Now, windows file didn't work, but `windows.tmux` file, did do the trick of opening `bash`, `nano`, and `htop`. Basically, that's what i have there.

```
$ cat .byobu/windows.tmux 
new-session bash ; 
new-window htop ;
new-window nano;
```

Now, since I am not so well versed with `tmux`, much less `tmuxrc` file, I can only give you this much. There is a `-c` flag, for starting directory, so for example I could do `new-session -c / bash ;` to start in root directory. But so far I've no idea how to make `vi` launch with a file